# Chrome: foreign object always appears on top

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg

I've faced with some problem trying to add foreign object to svg.
In Google Chrome foreign object is always displayed on top layer of svg despite the order of elements within svg.

There is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ttfpyf6x/) example

```
<svg width='400' height='400'>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400" fill='orange'></rect>
  <foreignObject>
    <div class='text-container'>
      <div class='text-title'>
        TITLE
      </div>
    </div>
  </foreignObject>
  <rect x="150" y="190" width="100" height="20" fill='red'></rect>
</svg>
```

Since the "title" could be placed dynamically within svg-canvas, it's important that the div contained text has `position: absolute`.

In FF and IE it displays correctly (by saying correctly I mean that red rectangle overlays word "title").

I know it's possible to display text via `<text>` of svg and it would be showed correctly in all browsers, but the main problem with `<text>` is its slow rendering (in case of hundred text elements).
So I'm looking for solution with foreign object particularly (or possibility to speed up `<text>`).

[image: Chrome (incorrect as I guess)]
[image: Firefox (correct)]

Left image - Chrome (incorrect), right image - firefox (the behavior i'm trying to get)

```css
.text-container {
  position: relative;
}

.text-title {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  top: 190px;
  left: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<svg width='400' height='400'>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400" fill='orange'></rect>
  <foreignObject>
    <div class='text-container'>
      <div class='text-title'>
        TITLE
      </div>
    </div>
  </foreignObject>
  <rect x="150" y="190" width="100" height="20" fill='red'></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: In my tests the red rectangle overlays the text (you have to change the positions to see that). Can you demonstrate your problem using the snippet feature ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret I can see that in Chrome, it doesn't (in the fiddle).

Comment: Updated my question with screens from browsers.

Comment: @user1820686 can't you hide the text with CSS instead of moving the element over?

Comment: @user1820686 use the snippet button. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @DenysSéguret I tried to edit the post to put it into a fiddle, but the exact same HTML & CSS are behaving differently on SO then in the Fiddle.. :S

Comment: @randy, unfortunately I can't just hide the text. My example is simplified. I need to display red rectangle above

Comment: @DenysSéguret, added a snippet

Comment: But... You totally changed the question by adding that `position:absolute`. As it's an essential part of the problem, put it in your question